# How to pick the "best" line equation that fits data and passes through the origin?

Tags: data-analysis, descriptive-statistics

I have some data shown in the image. Each symbol corresponds to a different dataset. As it can be seen the data initially behaves like a line and after some points it follows other behaviour.
[image]

The idea is to fit a line that passes through the origin and that the line "is good enough" approximating the behaviour of the data where it is linear.

What I tried is to do the following: I pick a minimum of data (e.g. $m_i$) for each data set $D_i = \{d_{ij}=(x_j,y_j)_i, j\in\{1,...,N_i\}\}$, where $N_i = |D_i|$ is the number of data of each set, and $x_1=0, x_p < x_q$ if $p < q$ . Now, for $D_i$ we consider subsets $S_{ik}=\{d_{ij}=(x_j,y_j)_i, j\in\{1,...,k_i\}\}$, where $k_i \in \{m_i,...,N_i\}$. Each of these subsets has associated with it a correlation coefficient $p_{ik}$. My idea was to pick the maximum of these coefficients and to fit a line $y=mx$ through the data in $S_{ik}$ associated with $\max_k p_{ik}$.

The problem with this is that the correlation coefficient tells how the $y$ data behaves with respect to the $x$ data, i.e. how good a line would fit the data. This line intercepts the $y$ axis at a point that in general is not $0$.

My next try was to instead fit a line $y=mx$ for each $S_{ik}$ and then compute the mean squared error MSE. Then pick the subset that is associated with the minimum value of MSE. This also fails because of course the minimum value is the one associated with the subset with less number of data (MSE penalizes the variation very hard, I look for something "softer").

Is there a way of knowing where the data behaves like a line passing through the origin? I was thinking of taking a small subset of data S_{ik}, fitting a line $y_i=mx$, computing the MSQ. Then adding one data point to the subset and computing its error, then compare it with the MSQ and decide whether to continue the process of adding data, or stopping.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: This will be inherently subjective. Compare to the fact that there is no absolute way of determining what counts as an "outlier" observation. Considering that you're likewise looking to ignore some of the data points, you will need to set the criteria for "minimum accepted correlation" or the like. My instinct here would be to not use linear regression; it looks more like parabolic (quadratic) regression to me, which might more cleanly resolve your problem.

Comment: I agree that fitting a straight line to these points looks like the wrong thing to do. But if you really must do this, you will have to tell us where the data comes from and what it will be used for. Otherwise we have no basis for any advice we might offer.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I'm interested in the linear part of the data because it follows some model. I want to conclude that the model is not useful for some points. But I want to get a way of determining the "best" part of the data that could be fit by a line. I'm aware that this is difficult (maybe there is a way).

Comment: @TonyK The data comes from examining the position of the free end of a cantilever subjected to a load at the free end, the load is the x axis and the vertical displacement is the y axis. Physically there is a domain in which the molecular arrangement of the cantilever's material produce a restoring force that makes the data behave linearly, following Hooke's law. After some load, we get that the molecular arrangement is damaged, causing the material to behave plastically (not linearly).

Comment: Thanks for that info. The top set of points, in particular, doesn't look linear over _any_ range $-$ do you have a physical explanation for this?

Comment: @TonyK, There is a DE that predicts every data point. However the linear model is widely used because most of materials behave linearly. The one I'm studying doesn't behave linearly. Still, I'm interested in the linear part to see if the slope of the line predicts one physical quantity. So I wanted to know if there is an objective method to determine which part of the data is linear (one could guess and write down: "it can be seen that the data behaves like a line up to this point", but I wanted a more robust argument).

Answer (score 2):

I worked this out
a number of years ago.

If you go the the process
of minimizing
$\sum (y_i-ax_i)^2$
as a function of $a$,
you get
$a
=\frac{\sum x_iy_i}{\sum x_i^2}
$.

Here's how the math works out:

Let
$D
=\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-ax_i)^2
$.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{\partial D}{\partial a}
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial (y_i-ax_i)^2}{\partial a}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n -2x_i(y_i-ax_i)\\
&=-2(\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i-a\sum_{i=1}^nx^2_i)\\
&=0
\qquad\text{when }a = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nx^2_i}\\
\end{array}
$

For this value of $a$,

$\begin{array}\\
D
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(y_i-ax_i\right)^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(y^2_i-2ax_iy_i+a^2x^2_i\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n y^2_i-2a\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i+a^2\sum_{i=1}^nx^2_i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n y^2_i-2\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nx^2_i}\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i+\left(\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nx^2_i}\right)^2\sum_{i=1}^nx^2_i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n y^2_i-\dfrac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i\right)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^nx^2_i}\\
\end{array}
$

Note that both the value of $a$
and the value of $D$
can be easily updated
when a data point
is either added or removed.
That way,
you can examine how $D$ changes
(though you probably want to compute
$\frac1{n}D$)
and stop when it gets too large.

Comment: But I'm interested in also knowing where do I "cut" the data to get just the part of it that behaves like a line.

Comment: Look at the mean error $\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-ax_i)^2$ for each value of $a$ as successive points are added, and stop when that gets too large.

Comment: Also, see my new, improved answer.

Comment: marty, I don't see the difference between this approach and the mean squared error. $D$ is just the mean squared error, right?. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Yes it is. But the MSE is easily updatable, so you can monitor it and stop when it gets too large.

Answer (score -1):

Are you required to use a straight line?  It looks to me like a quadratic would fit better and require only a little more trouble.

Comment: Hi, your answer should be a comment. It is some physical data and I'm interested in the linear part.

Comment: @VladimirVargas: The trouble is, there doesn't seem to be a linear part.